# Unable to nest navigators in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

This configuration is not working

but if I change the Tabs to Dummy1 it works :

`<Stack.Screen name="ConnectionList" component={Dummy1} options={{headerShown: false}}`

I don't understand the issue here.
Getting the error :

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead
```

This is the code that I have used for nesting ..

1. Login.
2. Nesting Bottom Tabs Nav
   But I am getting the above-mentioned error..

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="ConnectionList" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown: false}}
              
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      );
    }
}

const Dummy1= () => {
  return(
  <Text>Dummy1</Text>
          )
}

const Dummy2= () => {
  return(
  <Text>Dummy2</Text>
          )
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = async() => {

  return(
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Tab.Navigator 
        activeColor="#f0edf6"
        inactiveColor="#0c0c0c"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#694fad' }}
        >
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Dummy1" 
          component={Dummy1} 
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Dummy2" 
          component={Dummy2}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I have added a small part of package.json..
package.json --

```
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an async function for Tabs which is causing this issue

change

```
const Tabs = async() => {
```

to

```
const Tabs = () => {
```

The component you pass to the navigator should be a valid react functional component.

Comment: This helped .. thank you 
But I didn't understand why is async included not valid ..

Comment: think like this, an async function returns a promise and when you try to use it as a component you end up with and object in the tree, which causes an object without wrapper and causes the above error

Comment: Ohh nice thanks now I understand the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the tag

Instead of this

```
<Stack.Screen name="ConnectionList" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown: false}}
```

Write this

```
<Stack.Screen name="ConnectionList" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown: false}} />
```

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/nested-navigators)

Comment: Thank you .. I see your example is working .. I made a mistake as pointed by @Guru.. 
you too corrected that .. 
This mistake was made during editing .. otherwise this wouldn't have compiled .. right an bro